# How to select/unselect checkboxes in the child component by using a check box in parent component (Angular 9)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component in which there is a 'select all' check box. When I click on it, I want my child component's check boxes selected. Pleas help, thanks in advance
parent.component.html

```
<div>
<span>
<i style="padding-left: 10px"
       [ngClass]="selectAllToggle ? 'fa fa-check-circle' : 'fa fa-circle-o'"
       (click)="handleOverallTileClick()"></i>
</span>
</div>
<child [selectAllValue] ="selectAllToggle "></child>
```

parent.component.ts

```
handleOverallTileClick() {
        this.selectAllToggle = !this.selectAllToggle ;
        if (!this.selectAllToggle ) {
            this.selectAllToggle = false;
        } else {
            this.selectAllToggle = true;
        }
    }
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() selectAllValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a stackblitz example.

Your child component should look something like this.

`child.component.html`

```
<i [ngClass]="selectAllValue ? 'fa fa-check-circle' : 'fa fa-circle-o'"></i>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t1rkpa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Naman Jain thanks for answering. Actually in the child component also  I'm using <i> instead of <input type="checkbox"/>. In that case can you tell me how to set the values of each <i> to true?

Comment: I have modified the example accprdingly. Please check